# active record - get related records from has_and_belongs_to_many and has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using ruby active record

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :blogs
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

How do I get Blog users who have atleast 1 Post or 1 comment

something like this in pseudo code

```
Blog.users.where(posts.count > 1 || comments.count > 1)
```

Comment: Did you consider adding [`counter_cache`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache) to your models? The query would be much simpler and faster if you have implemented them.

Comment: @spickermann, I see that "With this declaration, Rails will keep the cache value up to date, and then return that value in response to the size method." I am not using rails. This is a sinatra app with ruby active record

Comment: `counter_cache` is an option of the `belongs_to` method which is part of ActiveRecord. Therefore it should work in your Sinatra app when you use ActiveRecord as your ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to use the following, though haven't been able to test:

```
users = Blog.users
users.left_outer_joins(:posts).where.not(posts: { user_id: nil })
  .or(
    users.left_outer_joins(:comments).where.not(comments: { user_id: nil })
  )

# or if you're on Rails < 5
query = <<-SQL
  SELECT users.* from users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = users.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON comments.user_id = users.id
  WHERE posts.user_id IS NOT NULL
  OR comments.user_id IS NOT NULL
SQL

users.where(query)
```

In a nutshell, this insists there is a post and a comment with a `user_id` present in the query. This definitely works when checking for the existence of one association, though I've not tried it using `or`.

I've got an older version of Rails running at the moment, and would love to hear whether this does work as I'd expect it to, so if you could let me know how you get on @user2624242, that would be great.

Comment: I apologize for the delay. 
I have tried left_outer_joins but it threw out an undefined method error.
NoMethodError: undefined method `left_outer_joins'

Comment: It sounds like you're on an older version of Rails then @user2624242. Could you clarify this please? Link to the docs [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins). It was introduced in Rails 5. I'll update my answer to include the old format regardless, which I hope will help :)

Comment: Update: urgh, `or` is Rails 5 too, updated to reflect this.

Comment: Did help at all in the end @user2624242?